# Reversing wordpress title tag

Tags: php, wordpress, title, codex

I would like to structure my title tags to display: Site Name | Page Title

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) this should work:

```
<?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

but it is rendering in reverse: Page Title | Site Name

Any other location where this is controlled, that may be causing an override?

Comment: Have you tried just swapping the order of the calls (ie put the wp_title(..) call *after* the bloginfo call)?

Comment: Yea, it renders Title | Name no matter the order. It seems like it might be a WP override, maybe in the functions? Is that probable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the codex, you can edit the title to do exactly what you are wanting to do.

```
<title><?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title('', false); ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No, this still renders the page title before the blog name.

Comment: @CareyEstes I forgot to add `false` to the `wp_title()` function. How about now?

Comment: No, still rendering in reverse :(